# dev driver install with linux kernel 3.0 fails

Tags: 11.10, drivers, nvidia

I tried install dev driver nvidia (ubuntu 11.10) 
my /var/log/nvidia-installer.log: http://pastebin.com/UPZsG4au
How to solve this problem?

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Mon Nov 21 12:42:03 2011
installer version: 270.41.19

PATH:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin

option status:
  license pre-accepted               : false
  update                             : false
  force update                       : false
  expert                             : false
  uninstall                          : false
  driver info                        : false
  precompiled interfaces             : true
  no ncurses color                   : false
  query latest version               : false
  no questions                       : false
  silent                             : false
  no recursion                       : false
  no backup                          : false
  kernel module only                 : false
  sanity                             : false
  add this kernel                    : false
  no runlevel check                  : false
  no network                         : false
  no ABI note                        : false
  no RPMs                            : false
  no kernel module                   : false
  force SELinux                      : default
  no X server check                  : false
  no cc version check                : false
  run distro scripts                 : true
  no nouveau check                   : false
  run nvidia-xconfig                 : false
  sigwinch work around               : true
  force tls                          : (not specified)
  force compat32 tls                 : (not specified)
  X install prefix                   : (not specified)
  X library install path             : (not specified)
  X module install path              : (not specified)
  OpenGL install prefix              : (not specified)
  OpenGL install libdir              : (not specified)
  compat32 install chroot            : (not specified)
  compat32 install prefix            : (not specified)
  compat32 install libdir            : (not specified)
  utility install prefix             : (not specified)
  utility install libdir             : (not specified)
  installer prefix                   : (not specified)
  doc install prefix                 : (not specified)
  kernel name                        : (not specified)
  kernel include path                : (not specified)
  kernel source path                 : (not specified)
  kernel output path                 : (not specified)
  kernel install path                : (not specified)
  precompiled kernel interfaces path : (not specified)
  precompiled kernel interfaces url  : (not specified)
  proc mount point                   : /proc
  ui                                 : (not specified)
  tmpdir                             : /tmp
  ftp mirror                         : ftp://download.nvidia.com
  RPM file list                      : (not specified)
  selinux chcon type                 : (not specified)

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> License accepted.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 270.41.19.
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="cc".
-> Performing CC version check with CC="cc".
-> Kernel source path: '/lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/build'
-> Kernel output path: '/lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/build'
ERROR: If you are using a Linux 2.4 kernel, please make sure
       you either have configured kernel sources matching your
       kernel or the correct set of kernel headers installed
       on your system.

       If you are using a Linux 2.6 kernel, please make sure
       you have configured kernel sources matching your kernel
       installed on your system. If you specified a separate
       output directory using either the "KBUILD_OUTPUT" or
       the "O" KBUILD parameter, make sure to specify this
       directory with the SYSOUT environment variable or with
       the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.

       Depending on where and how the kernel sources (or the
       kernel headers) were installed, you may need to specify
       their location with the SYSSRC environment variable or
       the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file
       '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions
       on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux
       driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs even if you have the linux headers in place. I have not found any solutions so far. The only solution I can come up with is to downgrade to a working kernel and xorg-xserver version.

However if you have an optimus platform downgrading seems to cause problems as far as I can see.

Waiting for nvidia to release working drivers for Linux kernel > 3 with correct a ABI version!

I submitted an application to download the RC 4.1 driver, maybe that will help. I will let you know if I have an answer.

**Update**
Thanks to Nvidia for fast response. I acquired 4.1 RC development driver (devdriver_4.1_linux_64_285.05.15.run).

This version builds the kernel module fine with 3.1.0-1-amd64 and xserver-xorg 1:7.6+9.

But I guess it can not detect the card due to Optimus settings. I will try the [Bumblebee](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/blob/master/README) project for that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it can't find kernel sources:

> If you are using a Linux 2.6 kernel, please make sure
>          you have configured kernel sources matching your kernel
>          installed on your system.

(suppose 3.0 is the same as 2.6)

To install kernel sources, do

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
```